# How to show and hide a virtual keyboard (android)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With Delphi (berlin) what is the good method to show and hide a virtual keyboard under Android ?

i put on my form a native android edit. i set setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false); and i try to open manually the keyboard like

```
  var aVirtualKeyboardService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
  TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(aVirtualKeyboardService));
  if (aVirtualKeyboardService <> nil) then aVirtualKeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard(self);
```

but it's not work :( sometime the keyboard is show, sometime not :(

Comment: A simple Google search is turning up plenty of helpful results for me...

Comment: @Jerry if i ask it's because what i see didn't work!

Comment: We don't know what you saw, because you didn't say anything about it in your post. We don't know why what you tried didn't work, because you a) didn't mention trying anything, and b) didn't post any code showing what you've tried. Based on what you wrote, you've done nothing, and you expect us to do it all for you (including the research). Spend some time reading [ask], and then come back and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [IFMXVirtualKeyboardService](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.VirtualKeyboard.IFMXVirtualKeyboardService). It has [ShowVirtualKeyboard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.VirtualKeyboard.IFMXVirtualKeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard) and [HideVirtualKeyboard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.VirtualKeyboard.IFMXVirtualKeyboardService.HideVirtualKeyboard) methods.

Comment: thanks sam, but unfortunatly when i do this, the form.OnVirtualKeyboardHidden and form.onVirtualKeyboardShown don't work correctly. it's for exemple fired but 5 seconds after the virtualkeyboard is showed :(

Comment: Your original question was how to show and hide the virtual keyboard, which for me, it works fine. Now You are asking about the events that happens as the result of showing/hiding the virtual keyboard. For that you have to be more specific. What device are you running this on? You are expecting the event to happen as a result of calling the ***ShowVirtualKeyboard*** or because you have made an edit field the active component? By the way why do you even need to show the keyboard manually? Without knowing what exactly you are trying to accomplish, It is not easy to help you.